How to save modifications of a repository when an exception is thrown after the repository.save(...) in the method
I code in java with Spring boot. I have a User entity with a name attribute. This entity has a UserRepository. I have a UserCommunication class:
public abstract class UserCommunication {

protected UserRepository userRepository; 

private void saveTheUser(User user, boolean throwOnBadStatusCode) {

   if(condition) {
            user.setName(“newName”);
            userRepository.save(user);

            if( throwOnBadStatusCode ) {
                throw new Exception;
            }
   }
}


I also have a UserCommunicationLocal class:
public class UserCommunicationLocal extends UserCommunication {

    public UserCommunicationLocal(User user) {
        super(user);
    }
}

I call the saveTheUser method in a @Service UserRegistration :
@Service
public class UserRegistration{

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  private void saveService(User user){
    UserCommunicationLocal communication = new UserCommunicationLocal(user);
    communication.saveTheUser(user, true);
  }

}

My problem is as follows: when i call the method saveService in my Job and when throwOnBadStatusCode is set to true, the exception is thrown and the repository is not saved, even if the code line userRepository.save(user) is executed before the exception. Because when I retrieve the users later in my application, the user's name hasn't changed. How can I remedy this? I think it has something to do with spring's Transaction, but I don't know how to fix it without managing transactions manually.
I'd like the exception to be thrown, but I'd still like the user name change to be registered.

what is if(condition) in this context ?

In some simple Spring-Boot application, the infra is controller -> service ->repository. You can save the entity in service component, create another communication is not a good idea.

I need to send a request and to retrieve the error message in the response of the request in reality. The if condition is if(response.statusCode()!=expectedResponseCode), in this case i need to save response.body() in the entity. My service call the method in UserCommunication.

I can not change the classes. I just need a way to save the good string in an entity by user.setName(...) and repository.save(user) (it is a crud repository) and that despite the exception after, the saving is well done. ( In reality it is not a user entity, it is just for the example ). My issue is that spring don't commit the saving in repository because of the exception.

can you provide complete code of  UserCommunicationLocal  and UserCommunication? , Please edit the post.
